# Different header image for each page in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, header

I have a WP theme that supports custom headers in the sense that I can upload any number of header images and it will randomize them as a user browses the site but what I need is for each page to display a single image from my Media Gallery that is related to the content on that page.

I've tried to add this to `custom-header.php`

```
if(is_page('About')){
echo '<img src="the-path-to-image/about.jpg" />';
```

OR this

```
<?php if(is_home) { ?>
<?php if( get_header_image() ): ?>
<div id="custom-img-header"><img src="the-path-to-image/about.jpg" alt=""
/></div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

but nothing changes ...

Code from `functions.php`

```
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/custom-header.php';
```

Code from `header.php`

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" <?php echo beluga_header_image_background(); ?> role="banner">
    <div class="masthead-opacity"></div>
    <div class="site-branding">
        <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
        <h2 class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
    </div>
</header>
```

Code from `custom-header.php`

```
<?php if ( get_header_image() ) : ?>
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
    <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" alt="">
</a>
<?php endif; // End header image check. ?>
```

Can anyone please help me with what and where should I modify to make it work ?

Comment: So, you are referring that you would like to display your featured image from a certain post as header for that post ?

Comment: Yes that would be good too ... I am satisfied as long as I can set a different header image for each page (i.e. on "About" page header img is uploads/about.jpg, on "Contact" page > uploads/contact.jpg )

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the following method for the banner header:

Header.php file

```
<?php 
$thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); 
if($thumb) {
    //If image is defined
    $background_set = 'style="background:url('.$thumb.')"';
} else {
    // If not image is defined
    $background_set = '';
}
?>  
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" <?php echo $background_set; ?> role="banner">
    <div class="masthead-opacity"></div>
    <div class="site-branding">
        <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
        <h2 class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
    </div>
</header>
```

By writing the above code we can achieve the banner image for each post. But, remember that the above code will search for the post thumbnail image from a page or a post and if found will output that image as the header banner.

Best what you can do is create a custom image upload meta field that displays on posts. Upload the image there and simply extract the meta content data and output it to the header.php file.

First try the above method and reply whether it works or not. Thanks. !